# How can I indicate if an object operates with another one in an UML class diagram?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

Suppose I want to draw a class diagram of a DAO and an Entity. The DAO is used to load instances of the Entity from the database. How can I represent this relationship on my class diagram? Is this considered one? I think it should be displayed on the diagram somehow:

[image]

**TL;DR**: should I draw something between them or not?

Comment: The GOF patterns are often illustrated by UML examples, for your case look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DAO loads data from DB and CREATES instances of Entity:

[image]

There is a special stereotype for such dependency. Class INSTANTIATES Class2, if it creates its instances. Exists in UML standard. ( I checked 2.4.1 - contemporary and 2.5 - the next one.)

Comment: how does this answer the question asked?

Comment: DAO loads data from DB and CREATES instances of Entity. It is EXACTLY the answer for the question.

Comment: @gnat Should we really repeat the question in the answer?

Comment: in this case yes, since question title missed the key point addressed by your answer

Answer (score 3):

The closest I can think of is a [usage](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rsmhelp/v7r5m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc%2Ftopics%2Fcusage.html) relationship. [Possible stereotypes](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsmhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc/topics/cdepend.html): "use", "call", "create", "instantiate", "send".

```
SomeDAO ---<<use>>---> SomeEntity
```